# select on-change chosen on-load entry

Tags: php, select, get

I have a form with a select that submits a value to a php query on-change but I'm having two issues.

I don't seem to be able to submit the first entry from the select list at any stage and when I select any other entry, though the query does return the correct data for that value the select itself display the first entry as chosen when ideally I want it to show the acttual entry that was chosen.

```
<form action=" " method="get">
<select class="form-control select2-single " id="p1" name="projects" 
onchange="this.form.submit()">
echo "<option value='$project_id'>$project_name</option>"; 
</form>



if(!isset($_GET["projects"])){
$project = 1;} else {
$project = $_GET["projects"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = $project";
}}
```

Expected:

- when selecting the first item from the select, the value should be sent to the php query.
- and when an item is chosen from the select, that item should be displayed as selected.

Actual:

- selecting the first option does nothing
- selecting the second options does return the correct data but is not chosen

Comment: Need to see the form markup.

Comment: updated to show form markup

Comment: a workaround I have discovered is to add another option value as a placeholder that then allows me to select all other entries and also masks the issue of the correct item not being chosen but it seems like there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The onchange will not fire when the value does not change. Adding a blank item will get you past that. Or maybe a java script library.

```
$options = [1,2,3,4];
echo '<form method="get">
<select class="form-control select2-single " id="p1" name="projects" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value=""></option>';

foreach($options as $option){
    $selected = '';
    if($_GET['projects'] == $option){
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo "<option value='$option' $selected >$option</option>";
}
echo '<select/></form>';
print_r($_GET);
```

Your open to sql injection, Need to use prepaired statement [bobby Tables](https://www.bobby-tables.com/)